# Error al tratar de capturar el valor de un @Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Tengo un formulario e el cual muestro un @Html.DropDownList, los datos que le estoy pasando se paso mediante un ViewBag el cual instancio al inicio de la vista,
al tratar de obtener el valor el jquery me genera el siguiente error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1580)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2232)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2659)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:884)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2922)
at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:3032)
at jQuery (jquery.js:98)
at c (bootstrap.min.js:21)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:21)
at Function.each (jquery.js:362)
```

Este es el error que me aparece en la consola de chrome
la forma en como intento capturar el valor es de la siguiente forma

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tipoAlerta").change(function () {
        var data = $('#tipoAlerta').val();
        alert(data);
    });

});
```

Este es el condigo html renderizado

```
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-header"></div>
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label">Tipo de alerta</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" id="tipoAlerta" name="tipoAlerta">
                    <option value="">- Seleccionar una -</option>
                    <option value="1">Alerta Acad&#233;mica</option>
                    <option value="2">Alerta Manual</option>
                    <option value="3">Alerta Financiera</option>
                    <option value="4">Alerta Familiar</option>
                    <option value="5">Alerta Salud</option>
                    <option value="6">Alerta de notas</option>
                    <option value="12">Hola Mundo Actualizo??</option>
                    <option value="13">Prueba Actualizo Y mostr&#243; ???</option>
                    <option value="14">probando</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estoy trabajando con asp.net mvc 4, la forma en como envio los datos por el ViewBag es la siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["Estado"] = 7;
        Sto_TiposAlertas_NE STANE = new Sto_TiposAlertas_NE();
        SelectList listaTipoAlerta = new SelectList(STANE.ListaTipoAlertas(), "TipoAlerta", "Nombre");
        ViewBag.ListaTipoAlerta = listaTipoAlerta;
        return View();
    }
```

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este error

Comment: coloca el html que renderiza para ver el select,,

Comment: Coloca tu layout general :D

Comment: Puedes asegurarnos que el error lo esta lanzando en ese script?  El script esta bien por lo que puede ser otro script  donde este fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice un ejemplo similar al tuyo y la forma en que obtengo el valor es la siguiente:

```
$("#miCombo").change(function () {  //Obtengo el valor en cuanto elijen una opción del combo
        IdValue= $("#miCombo").val();
})
```

y lo inicializo así:

```
@Html.DropDownList("miCombo", ViewData["MyViewBag"] as SelectList, new { @IdValue= "Value", @class = "class" }) // Donde new{} es una condición que uso para los datos
```

Answer (score 0):

Está extraño pues de inicio pareciera tu jquery no se está cargando, pero si fuera el caso te marcaría el error desde *$(document).ready(fu...*

De todos modos para no dejarlo, pudieras incluir tu código javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tipoAlerta").change(function () {
                var data = $('#tipoAlerta').val();
                alert(data);
            });
    });
    </script>
}
```

Con eso aseguras que primero se cargue el jquery, y después tu código.